# Microsoft Graph - problems with numbers and date formats when converting Excel (xlsx) to PDF

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

Using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http to convert Excel (xlsx) files to PDF works fine, EXCEPT one thing: numbers and dates in the exported PDF are presented only in English-US formatting!

I need numbers in "1.000,21" and dates "dd / mm / yyyy".

And nothing in the documentation is referring about how to inform Graph to convert to PDF but using a localization for example, "pt-BR".

Thanks for any help!

Comment: We are looking into this.

Comment: Thank you @Shiva-MSFTIdentity. We hope that is possible to use this feature but formatting acording to our localization.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity any news?

Comment: Not yet. You can track the progress from [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10929).